# updating database field when a checkbox for an element is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

here is what i have so far :sql that gets data from the database, the data is passed through a loop and then displayed with the html code

```
$sql = "SELECT items_available.title, 
                items_available.item_number, 
                items_available.subtitle, 
                items_available.image_name, 
                users.username 
        FROM items_available
            INNER JOIN users ON items_available.owner_id = users.user_id
        WHERE items_available.status ='pending' 
        LIMIT $query_limit ;";

$query = mysql_query($sql);

while ($dbData = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $item_id      = $dbData['item_number'];
    $sel_title    = $dbData ['title'];
    $sel_Image    = $dbData['image_name'];
    $sel_subtitle = $dbData['subtitle'];
    $sel_owner    = $dbData['username'];


    echo "<span style='display:inline-block;width:185px;margin:4px;'>
        <a href='#'>
            <img src='upload/$sel_Image' style='width:180px; height:160px;' />
                <h5 style='display:inline;'>$sel_title </h5><br>
                <h7 style='display:inline;'> $sel_subtitle</h7><br>
                <h6 style='display:inline;'>Posted by $sel_owner</h6> 
        </a>|
        <div style= \"display:inline-block;\"> 
            <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"check\" name='item_ids[]' value='1' />
        </div>
    </span>";

}/
```

the checkbox below the block of codes should grab the ids of each element so an update to the database is possible.Hope my description is clear enough to be aided

Comment: what is your question?  as written,  it almost looks like you are asking for a code rrview,  not asking for help with something that is goi g wron

Comment: what u want to update by those ids ?

Comment: I simply need to know how to grab the individual id's of the elements in the loop when the checkbox is clicked so i can perform an update query

Answer (score 0):

you did nt give any specfic so it is like a guide for what u asking 
you need to create a form here with a hidden field

like

```
<div style= \"display:inline-block;\">
<form method=\"post\">
 <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"value\" =". $item_id.">
 <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"update\" value = '1' />
</form>
</div>
```

php for that ll look like

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['value']))

{

//update after validation
}
```

P.S $_REQUEST Deals with both for GET or POST method 
it actually depends what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can make the VALUE of the checkbox into the id you want to get back in the `$_POST['item_ids']` array.

```
<div style= \"display:inline-block;\"> ";

echo '<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="item_ids[]" value="' . $item_id . '" />';

echo "</div>
```

Now in your PHP code you can process them like this, remember checkboxes are only returned in the $_POST/$_GET array if they are actually checked.

I am assuming $_POST.

```
if ( isset($_POST['item_ids']) ) {
    foreach ( $_POST['item_ids'] as $item_id ) {

        // do whatever you want to with this information

    }
}
```

Comment: tnx was helpful but used jquery and ajax to solve the problem